# ATMega328-PU misread ADC values

Tags: atmega328p

I am working on an embedded systems project using an Arduino Uno, and I wanted to convert my project over to a breadboard using the ATMega328-PU IC with the bootloader.  Initially, this worked flawlessly, and I was satisfied with the results.

However, I wanted to incorporate ADC analysis into my project.  So first I made sure that the project ran smoothly off of the Arduino Uno, which it did.  When I loaded the code to the IC, however, I noticed that all of my read-in ADC values had dropped by ~20%.  I measured the voltage at the pin using an o-scope, and the readings from the scope were accurate to what I expected, so I was not inclined to believe that it was a voltage problem.  Besides, all other features of my project appear to be working perfectly fine - it is ONLY the ADC that is spitting back undesired results.  I am even trying to feed it a DC voltage to avoid any oscillation, and it is still giving me 20% less than the applied value.  From reading online, I know it is a common problem, so to be clear, my IC and the applied source do share a common ground.

I am currently a college student, doing this project for fun, so I asked one of my professors for advice, and he suggested decoupling my breadboard VCC and GND rails using a 0.1uF capacitor.  So, I tried this, but it showed absolutely no improvement.

Later today I can make a block diagram of my project, if that would be helpful.  But in the meantime, I will briefly describe it:

As stated, the project uses the ATMega328-PU, and I have applied a 16MHz oscillator to the clock pins, which are respectively in series with 22pF capacitors that go to ground.  The Rx/Tx pins are used to communicate with an HC-05 bluetooth module (paired to a smartphone, controlled by an app).  A digital pin is assigned to an LED in series with a resistor.  A 9V battery powers the project by first passing through a 5V voltage regulator that feeds the 5V output to the VCC rails and the ground to the GND rails.  The unregulated battery supply is passed through a voltage divider to drop it by 5/9.  This divided voltage is then passed to an analog input pin on the ATMega.  Since the values were not particularly consistent, a smoothing capacitor was also placed between the analog input and ground since there is an occasional (and undesired) fluctuation in the applied analog input.  I have tried to measure with and without this capacitor, but the margin of error is the same.

Since the Arduino handles the code with this circuitry just fine, I am convinced that it is not a software problem.  Also, it is only when the programmed chip is placed on the breadboard that I get these false readings.  Therefore, I believe either I should have used a different decoupling capacitor along my rails (though 0.1uF seems to be the consensus when I look online...) or I am missing some additional external circuitry that the Arduino has but my breadboard does not (though, if it exists, I cannot find any references to any additional circuitry for this...).  I would like to state again, the other features of the project work fine.  It just seems to be the ADC that is struggling to perform correctly.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: So works fine on a PCB with a ground plane and lots of bypassing. Place a 10uF, or 100uF, across the IC. Use very short leads ( < 1 cm).

Comment: Have you got the exact same connections for all VCC, AVCC, GND, and AREF pins like on Arduino?

Comment: @Justme Yes, I have checked a number of times, and all of those connections match that of the Arduino

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Thanks for the suggestion!   Just for my own understanding, when placing the 10/100 uF cap across the IC, you mean placing it across the VCC and GND pins of the IC?

Comment: How was the Uno powered? With a confirmed 5V source also?

Comment: Random guess: One of your resistor dividers is upside down. Accidentally dividing by 4/9 instead of 5/9 would give that exact 20% difference, and if you swap the resistors in a 5/9 divider you get a 4/9 divider.

Comment: @CrossRoads I powered the Uno originally via USB power cable and secondly via the 5V output of the voltage regulator.  The Uno output all ADC reads as expected under both sources

Comment: @Hearth Thanks for the suggestion, I have verified that the voltage divider is indeed set up properly.  I have measured the output of the divider on an o-scope to verify this as well.  The divider value, when passed to the Uno, gives correct results.  But off of the same divider, when passed to the IC, I am getting incorrect results.  Therefore, I do not think the divider is a contributing factor

Comment: What reference are you selecting?

Comment: Are you certain you have the same voltages on AREF and AVCC as the Arduino Uno?

Comment: @KevinWhite presently, my AVCC is tied to the regulated 5V, whereas my AREF is floating because (as I was under the impression that) the default reference is 5V, no?  Since the AREF was floating on the Uno (and the project was functioning properly), I assumed that the same would hold true when taking the IC is off-board.  I've read that when using AREF I need to A.) not exceed 5V and B.) use code to set AREF as the reference.  Is this something that would be required for my case, in your opinion?

Comment: @evildemonic AVCC is currently tied to my regulated 5V.  I have left AREF floating, which was it's state when I was using the Uno.  When going off-board, am I required to set the AREF?  I was under the impression that the default reference was 5V, but I am still fairly new to this specific microcontroller, so I will admit to not being entirely certain

Comment: @KCFord It depends on how you have REFS1 and REFS0 set in your ADMUX register.  If you are using AVCC or the internal voltage reference set then it won't use the value at AREF, however, you should still have a capacitor hooked up to that pin.

Comment: In Arduino, default appears to be that the VCC (5V) is selected as AREF, so AREF pin can be left floating. What have you selected as reference, and how - are you using Arduino libraries? Arduino has a 100nF capacitor on AREF pin, but it should not matter so much that readings are so much off. Double check that VCC and AVCC have good connection to 5V on breadboard, so that there is no loose connection even if you think there is a properly attached wire.

Comment: @KCFord - do you measure zero when you apply zero to the input?